# Attempting to randomize a data frame twice and add both of those samples to a new data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, sampling

So I have a data frame:

```
> MLSpredictions
        fit    se.fit residual.scale      upr      lwr
1  1.392213 0.1476321              1 1.681572 1.102854
2  1.448370 0.1709856              1 1.783501 1.113238
3  1.392213 0.1476321              1 1.681572 1.102854
4  1.448370 0.1709856              1 1.783501 1.113238
5  1.448370 0.1709856              1 1.783501 1.113238
6  1.448370 0.1709856              1 1.783501 1.113238
7  1.506792 0.1969097              1 1.892734 1.120849
8  1.506792 0.1969097              1 1.892734 1.120849
9  1.567570 0.2253572              1 2.009270 1.125870
10 1.567570 0.2253572              1 2.009270 1.125870
11 1.630800 0.2563338              1 2.133214 1.128386
12 1.448370 0.1709856              1 1.783501 1.113238
13 1.448370 0.1709856              1 1.783501 1.113238
14 1.448370 0.1709856              1 1.783501 1.113238
15 1.506792 0.1969097              1 1.892734 1.120849
16 1.567570 0.2253572              1 2.009270 1.125870
17 1.567570 0.2253572              1 2.009270 1.125870
18 1.567570 0.2253572              1 2.009270 1.125870
19 1.567570 0.2253572              1 2.009270 1.125870
```

I would like to sample this entire data frame TWICE and add both of those samples to a new data frame, MLSSeason:

My attempt was:

```
MLSSeason[1:19] = sample(MLSpredictions)
MLSSeason[20:38] = sample(MLSpredictions)
```

but that does not give me the right solution. Ideally, MLSSeason will have 38 rows with two of each MLSprediction sampled inside.

Comment: `MLSSeason = sample(MLSpredictions)` works but when I try to double the season of MLSSeason, I have some trouble.

Comment: Use `MLSpredictions[sample(nrow(MLSpredictions)),]`

Comment: `df[sample(1:(nrow(df)*2))/2,]` should work where df is `MLSprediction‌​s`. It will give you row names indicating which are duplicates, e.g., row 4.1 is the repeated sample of row 4.

Comment: @shayaa that works. Thanks a lot. Can you explain was is going on in that code. I see we sample from 1:38 then divide that by 2. I'm not quite sure how that got us the solution.

Comment: We multiply by two so that we get 38 rows and divide by 2 so that we index the proper row in the original data frame.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't feed a data frame to `sample`. It won't give you any error, but the data frame is returned unchanged. Instead, you should generate the row index.

```
MLSSeason <- MLSpredictions[c(sample(nrow(MLSpredictions)), sample(nrow(MLSpredictions))), ]
```

Note, this is not equivalent to:

```
MLSpredictions[samp‌​le(nrow(MLSprediction‌​s)),]
```

where you can't have duplicated rows.

Answer (score 1):

If you feed a data frame to sample, it will sample the columns of the data frame, not the rows.

The following code will sample each row twice, letting you know which rows are sampled a first or second time.

```
MLSprediction‌​s[sample(1:(nrow(MLSprediction‌​s)*2))/2,]
```

It will give you informative row names, e.g., where `11.1` is the second occurrence of the row `11`.

```
          fit    se.fit residual.scale      upr      lwr
16   1.567570 0.2253572              1 2.009270 1.125870
5    1.448370 0.1709856              1 1.783501 1.113238
11   1.630800 0.2563338              1 2.133214 1.128386
15   1.506792 0.1969097              1 1.892734 1.120849
1    1.392213 0.1476321              1 1.681572 1.102854
12   1.448370 0.1709856              1 1.783501 1.113238
11.1 1.630800 0.2563338              1 2.133214 1.128386
7    1.506792 0.1969097              1 1.892734 1.120849
```

If you desire that there be a block formation of the samples, e.g., every row is guaranteed to be sampled once every 19 rows then @ZheyuanLi provides the ideal answer. If not, my answer is probably best for you.